# Create a trust certificat between 2 PC

Tags: java, linux, openssl, keystore, pem

My server is Windows Server with a Java keystore running by JBoss.
I know how the set JBoss, so no problem with JBoss.

My client is Linux Redhat with openssl.
I want make it's work with "wget" (on https) with only a PEM certificate.
The final test is a third-party application running only PEM certificate.

I want build self-trust certificate between those 2 computers.

I try many many many thing...
...
and at the end, nothing fully worked.

Can someone help me? Just write all the commandline, and I'll figure out the rest.

Comment: You are aware that you need special voodoo to make Java accept a self-signed certificate?

Comment: I'm not aware... but sound possible I think. One of my test was to do something kinda "unsecured" but it's just a test: take public key and master certificate from my keystore and put them on my linux computer. wget connect well using the public key and the certificate as params (wget --no-check-certificate --private-key=dev-private.pem --certificate=dev.pem https://?.?.?.?)(I don't want add it in my ca anyway the application doesn't use ca). So I think I just need to understand how I should exchange key between java keystore (keytool) and wget for make it work with just a certificate.

Comment: Try searching for "java self-signed certificate"

Comment: I read tons of "how to" but I ask on this forum because I don't find the answer that I needed. Most of them just tell, do this this and most of them doesn't explain properly what you have done and why you do this. Or you have partial answer but when you doesn't know exactly what you have to do, it's hard to figure out. I have figure out most of it, but I wasn't able to determine which side should create a _certificate request_ and how I should build a _certificate_ from it. Perhaps with just an answer to those 2 questions I should be able to figure out the correct step.

Comment: In that case I would suggest you reword your question to clarify what you actually know.

Comment: Most commandline could be found here [link]http://shib.kuleuven.be/docs/ssl_commands.shtml . I have 2 computers: a server running a Java keystore and one client running linux Redhat. I want build a certificate between the 2 computers. The final result must be a PEM certificate running with the command "wget --no-check-certificate --certificate=dev.pem https://?.?.?.?) The thing I don't know is which computer create the request certificate and how I turn the request certificate in certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a Server A, and a client B.

For configure server A to use TLS mutual-authentication mechanism, your server must have a keypair and a "reference" to authenticate your client B and inversely.

Now, for testing, you can create a CA (Certification Authority) for signing certificate using by serverA with these command:

```
[1] ~# openssl genrsa -out caServerA.key 1024
[2] ~# openssl req -new -key caServerA.key -out caServerA.csr
[3] ~# openssl ca -selfsign -keyfile caServerA.key -in caServer.csr -out caServerA.crt
```

Generate keypair for server A, and sign it with CA previously created:

```
[1] ~# openssl genrsa -out serverA.key 1024
[2] ~# openssl req -new -key serverA.key -out serverA.csr
[3] ~# openssl ca -keyfile caServerA.key -cert caServerA.csr -in serverA.csr -out serverA.crt
```

Repeat the same process for client side. And at the end you must have some thing like:
clientB.crt, clientB.key, caClientB.crt.

Supposing that your server is an apache2, so you have to configure your https stuf with:

```
[....]
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile      [path_to_your_certificate]/serverA.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   [path_to_your_certificate]/serverA.key
# this because you have to trust all clients that have certificates signed by caClientB
SSLCACertificateFile    [path_to_your_certificate]/caClientB.crt
# this will force server to verify client's identity/certificate
SSLVerifyClient require
[....]
```

Restart your server, and it's ready to authenticate your clients.

For testing, it's more simple to use a Web browser to connect to server. But before doing that, you must export your keypair in PKCS12 format with this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in clientB.crt -inkey clientB.key -out clientB.pkcs12
```

Now you can import this file in "key manangement system" of your preferred browser. Connect to your server and this would work.

You can also activate Loglevel in debuging mode to have more details.

hope it helps ...

Answer (score 0):

you seem to talk only about keystore. If you want to use mutual-authentication between client-server, in JAVA or others, you must have a kind of truststore.

In practice, your truststore holds all CA certificates (not public key) that signed certificates of clients that you allow to talk to your server. And, to indentify your server, your client have to have your CA certificate (CA that signed your server's certificate).

It's like when you go to Cambodia, you government have to be in relation with the government of Combodia, if not, the customs services of Cambodia could not identify you ...

Hope it helps

Comment: Exactly. When I have autorisation of both gouverment, no trouble.

Comment: Exactly. When I have autorisation of both gouverment, no trouble. My main problem is make a relation with the both gouvernment. I can make a "certificate request" but I have no idea how to make it accepted by the other gouvernment (and which gouvernment should make the request). And no one seem exactly know how to do this with a java keystore. This became my main priority next week, so perhaps I'll figure out.